# Split and rearrange a data frame in list using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using R and with a data frame that has data for different years and various countries(numeric) 
I need to split it and rearrange them in various lists (9col and 22Rows) based on the country and the years(the xcolumns) . I have represented it in .xls as it was easier for the explanation. Or at least I hope so!!
this is a extract of the dataset. there is the rowRef and colRef that are to indicate the position where the data should go in the list.

here is an example data frame
 
 `ColRef <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,4),rep(5,4),rep(7,7),rep(9,3))
  RowRef <- c(1:3,8,19,22,1:3,8,1:3,8,1:3,15,8,19,22,1:3)
  country <- c(rep(2,19),rep(4,5))
  X2007 <- c(986,421,33,2,NA,NA,653,355,90,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,16,6,0,0,3,NA,NA,1650,777,123)
  X2008 <- c(1092,376,44,1,NA,NA,3581,289,95,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,17,4,0,NA,5,NA,NA,4667,666,139)
  X2009 <- c(1307,346,71,2,NA,NA,3182,301,121,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,26,12,0,0,9,NA,NA,4499,647,192)
X2010 <- c(1536,348,56,1,NA,NA,4441,718,224,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,24,10,0,NA,0,NA,NA,5991,1069,281)
  DataMix <- data.frame(ColRef,RowRef, country, X2007, X2008,X2009,X2010)`

[image]

And below is the representation of the wanted result  -> a list with various lists each of (9colx22rows)for each country and for each year. The number that had RefCol 1 and RefRow 1 become the first element, etc... the column named x2007 ... etc are the different years.

If anyone could tell me how to do this in R, I would be most grateful, as I am struggling around not reaching any result ! I have been searching for a solution but I could not find it. Maybe I have the wrong approach and keywords. Thank you

[image: country 2 year 2007]

[image: country 2 year 2008]

[image: country 4 year 2007]

Comment: Pls share your data in a way that we can use them. Screenshots are useless in this context. It would also be helpful if you could give us the code you have been trying so far.

Comment: Take a look at the reshape package. Specifically the `cast` function.

Comment: @vaettchen  - I understand very well that screenshots are useless, Sorry for this. The data were coming from various csv tables, combined and it was difficult for me to recreate them with code.  I have managed to split the tables for each country, with DataMixC <- split(DataMix, with(DataMix, interaction(Country)), drop = TRUE) but I have the impression I am going the wrong way. That this should be done after..

Comment: @Kliron, I did try the cast, but I suppose I do not understand how to use it. I tried this after the above to try on one country: DataMixTest1 <- DataMixC[[1]]   and then DMTest <-cast(DataMixTest1, RowRef ~ ColRef).  But I got "sing X2014 as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice" ; I am trying to learn, searching around. But this table looks to me like a lot of cast to do ... and I am lost in the approach.

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces just a tiny fraction of your initial table. Just subscript your main data frame or create a dummy data frame with the appropriate columns and some fake data. You don't need any complicated coding for that. People will be more willing to help you if you give them something to work on.

Comment: @Kliron and vaettche, you are completely right. I did add it. I Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my answer based on the dataset you provided.
Note that I'm still naming it `dt` and the `Country` column has a capital "C".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ColRef <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,4),rep(5,4),rep(7,7),rep(9,3))
RowRef <- c(1:3,8,19,22,1:3,8,1:3,8,1:3,15,8,19,22,1:3)
Country <- c(rep(2,19),rep(4,5))
X2007 <- c(986,421,33,2,NA,NA,653,355,90,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,16,6,0,0,3,NA,NA,1650,777,123)
X2008 <- c(1092,376,44,1,NA,NA,3581,289,95,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,17,4,0,NA,5,NA,NA,4667,666,139)
X2009 <- c(1307,346,71,2,NA,NA,3182,301,121,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,26,12,0,0,9,NA,NA,4499,647,192)
X2010 <- c(1536,348,56,1,NA,NA,4441,718,224,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,24,10,0,NA,0,NA,NA,5991,1069,281)
dt <- data.frame(ColRef,RowRef, Country, X2007, X2008,X2009,X2010)

dt

#    ColRef RowRef Country X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010
# 1       1      1       2   986  1092  1307  1536
# 2       1      2       2   421   376   346   348
# 3       1      3       2    33    44    71    56
# 4       1      8       2     2     1     2     1
# 5       1     19       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6       1     22       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7       2      1       2   653  3581  3182  4441
# 8       2      2       2   355   289   301   718
# 9       2      3       2    90    95   121   224
# 10      2      8       2     1     1     3     7
# 11      5      1       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 12      5      2       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13      5      3       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 14      5      8       2    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 15      7      1       2    16    17    26    24
# 16      7      2       2     6     4    12    10
# 17      7      3       2     0     0     0     0
# 18      7     15       2     0    NA     0    NA
# 19      7      8       2     3     5     9     0
# 20      7     19       4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 21      7     22       4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 22      9      1       4  1650  4667  4499  5991
# 23      9      2       4   777   666   647  1069
# 24      9      3       4   123   139   192   281


# create vector of unique countries and X columns
Country_vector = unique(dt$Country)
X_vector = dt %>% select(matches("X")) %>% names()

# create a list to store results
List_res = list()

# starting point of list element counter
n = 1

for (i in Country_vector) {  # i is the countries
  for (j in X_vector) {  # j is the X columns

    # keep appropriate rows and columns
    dt_test =
      dt %>%
      filter(Country == i) %>%
      select(ColRef, RowRef, matches(j)) 

    # create all possible combinations of ColRef and RowRef
    dt_test2 =
      expand.grid(ColRef = seq(min(dt$ColRef), max(dt$ColRef)),
                  RowRef = seq(min(dt$RowRef), max(dt$RowRef))) %>%
      left_join(dt_test, by=c("ColRef","RowRef"))   # join your actual values

    # rename your X column so you can handle it no matter what your input is
    names(dt_test2)[3] = "X"

    # replace NA values with zeros
    dt_test2[,"X"] = ifelse(is.na(dt_test2[,"X"]), 0, dt_test2[,"X"])

    # reshape dataset
    dt_test2 %>%
      spread(ColRef, X) -> List_res[[n]]

    # set the name of that element based on specific country and X column (at this iteration)
    names(List_res)[n] = paste(i,j)

    # get ready for next element and next iteration
    n = n+1
  } 
}


# check results
List_res

# $`2 X2007`
# RowRef   1   2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9
# 1       1 986 653 0 0 0 0 16 0 0
# 2       2 421 355 0 0 0 0  6 0 0
# 3       3  33  90 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 4       4   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 5       5   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 6       6   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 7       7   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 8       8   2   1 0 0 0 0  3 0 0
# 9       9   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 10     10   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 11     11   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 12     12   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 13     13   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 14     14   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 15     15   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 16     16   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 17     17   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 18     18   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 19     19   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 20     20   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 21     21   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 22     22   0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 
# $`2 X2008`
# RowRef    1    2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9
# 1       1 1092 3581 0 0 0 0 17 0 0
# 2       2  376  289 0 0 0 0  4 0 0
# 3       3   44   95 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 4       4    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 5       5    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 6       6    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 7       7    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 8       8    1    1 0 0 0 0  5 0 0
# 9       9    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 10     10    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 11     11    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 12     12    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 13     13    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 14     14    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 15     15    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 16     16    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 17     17    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 18     18    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 19     19    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 20     20    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 21     21    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 22     22    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 
# $`2 X2009`
# RowRef    1    2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9
# 1       1 1307 3182 0 0 0 0 26 0 0
# 2       2  346  301 0 0 0 0 12 0 0
# 3       3   71  121 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 4       4    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 5       5    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 6       6    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 7       7    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 8       8    2    3 0 0 0 0  9 0 0
# 9       9    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 10     10    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 11     11    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 12     12    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 13     13    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 14     14    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 15     15    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 16     16    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 17     17    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 18     18    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 19     19    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 20     20    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 21     21    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 22     22    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 
# $`2 X2010`
# RowRef    1    2 3 4 5 6  7 8 9
# 1       1 1536 4441 0 0 0 0 24 0 0
# 2       2  348  718 0 0 0 0 10 0 0
# 3       3   56  224 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 4       4    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 5       5    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 6       6    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 7       7    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 8       8    1    7 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 9       9    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 10     10    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 11     11    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 12     12    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 13     13    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 14     14    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 15     15    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 16     16    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 17     17    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 18     18    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 19     19    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 20     20    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 21     21    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 22     22    0    0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0
# 
# $`4 X2007`
# RowRef 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    9
# 1       1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1650
# 2       2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  777
# 3       3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  123
# 4       4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 5       5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 6       6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 7       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 8       8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 9       9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 10     10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 11     11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 12     12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 13     13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 14     14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 15     15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 16     16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 17     17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 18     18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 19     19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 20     20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 21     21 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 22     22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 
# $`4 X2008`
# RowRef 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    9
# 1       1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4667
# 2       2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  666
# 3       3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  139
# 4       4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 5       5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 6       6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 7       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 8       8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 9       9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 10     10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 11     11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 12     12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 13     13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 14     14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 15     15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 16     16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 17     17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 18     18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 19     19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 20     20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 21     21 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 22     22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 
# $`4 X2009`
# RowRef 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    9
# 1       1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4499
# 2       2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  647
# 3       3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  192
# 4       4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 5       5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 6       6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 7       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 8       8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 9       9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 10     10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 11     11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 12     12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 13     13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 14     14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 15     15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 16     16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 17     17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 18     18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 19     19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 20     20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 21     21 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 22     22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 
# $`4 X2010`
# RowRef 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    9
# 1       1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5991
# 2       2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1069
# 3       3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  281
# 4       4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 5       5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 6       6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 7       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 8       8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 9       9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 10     10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 11     11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 12     12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 13     13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 14     14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 15     15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 16     16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 17     17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 18     18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 19     19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 20     20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 21     21 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
# 22     22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0
```

I'm adding another approach which gives you the same result, not in separate lists, but in a big data frame with 2 key columns `Country` and `X` and also doesn't need to use a for loop (not a fan of loops personally).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ColRef <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,4),rep(5,4),rep(7,7),rep(9,3))
RowRef <- c(1:3,8,19,22,1:3,8,1:3,8,1:3,15,8,19,22,1:3)
Country <- c(rep(2,19),rep(4,5))
X2007 <- c(986,421,33,2,NA,NA,653,355,90,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,16,6,0,0,3,NA,NA,1650,777,123)
X2008 <- c(1092,376,44,1,NA,NA,3581,289,95,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,17,4,0,NA,5,NA,NA,4667,666,139)
X2009 <- c(1307,346,71,2,NA,NA,3182,301,121,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,26,12,0,0,9,NA,NA,4499,647,192)
X2010 <- c(1536,348,56,1,NA,NA,4441,718,224,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,24,10,0,NA,0,NA,NA,5991,1069,281)
dt <- data.frame(ColRef,RowRef, Country, X2007, X2008,X2009,X2010)

# reshape dataset
dt2 = dt %>% gather(X,value,X2007:X2010)

# function
ff = function(i,j){
  expand.grid(ColRef = seq(min(dt$ColRef), max(dt$ColRef)),
              RowRef = seq(min(dt$RowRef), max(dt$RowRef))) %>%
    left_join(dt2[dt2$Country==i & dt2$X==j,], by=c("ColRef","RowRef")) %>%
    select(-Country, -X) %>%
    spread(ColRef, value)}

# create all combinations between country and X values and apply the function
expand.grid(Country = unique(dt2$Country),
            X = unique(dt2$X)) %>%
  group_by(Country, X) %>%
  do(ff(.$Country, .$X)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%       ## don't really need it if you don't mind keeping the grouping
  print(n = nrow(.))  ## needed only to view/print all rows

# Source: local data frame [176 x 12]
# 
#     Country      X RowRef     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
#       (dbl) (fctr)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1         2  X2007      1   986   653    NA    NA    NA    NA    16    NA    NA
# 2         2  X2007      2   421   355    NA    NA    NA    NA     6    NA    NA
# 3         2  X2007      3    33    90    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 4         2  X2007      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5         2  X2007      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6         2  X2007      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7         2  X2007      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 8         2  X2007      8     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA    NA
# 9         2  X2007      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 10        2  X2007     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 11        2  X2007     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 12        2  X2007     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 13        2  X2007     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 14        2  X2007     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 15        2  X2007     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 16        2  X2007     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 17        2  X2007     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 18        2  X2007     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 19        2  X2007     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 20        2  X2007     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 21        2  X2007     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 22        2  X2007     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 23        2  X2008      1  1092  3581    NA    NA    NA    NA    17    NA    NA
# 24        2  X2008      2   376   289    NA    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA
# 25        2  X2008      3    44    95    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 26        2  X2008      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 27        2  X2008      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 28        2  X2008      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 29        2  X2008      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 30        2  X2008      8     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA     5    NA    NA
# 31        2  X2008      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 32        2  X2008     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 33        2  X2008     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 34        2  X2008     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 35        2  X2008     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 36        2  X2008     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 37        2  X2008     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 38        2  X2008     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 39        2  X2008     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 40        2  X2008     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 41        2  X2008     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 42        2  X2008     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 43        2  X2008     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 44        2  X2008     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 45        2  X2009      1  1307  3182    NA    NA    NA    NA    26    NA    NA
# 46        2  X2009      2   346   301    NA    NA    NA    NA    12    NA    NA
# 47        2  X2009      3    71   121    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 48        2  X2009      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 49        2  X2009      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 50        2  X2009      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 51        2  X2009      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 52        2  X2009      8     2     3    NA    NA    NA    NA     9    NA    NA
# 53        2  X2009      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 54        2  X2009     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 55        2  X2009     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 56        2  X2009     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 57        2  X2009     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 58        2  X2009     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 59        2  X2009     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 60        2  X2009     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 61        2  X2009     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 62        2  X2009     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 63        2  X2009     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 64        2  X2009     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 65        2  X2009     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 66        2  X2009     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 67        2  X2010      1  1536  4441    NA    NA    NA    NA    24    NA    NA
# 68        2  X2010      2   348   718    NA    NA    NA    NA    10    NA    NA
# 69        2  X2010      3    56   224    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 70        2  X2010      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 71        2  X2010      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 72        2  X2010      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 73        2  X2010      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 74        2  X2010      8     1     7    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA
# 75        2  X2010      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 76        2  X2010     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 77        2  X2010     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 78        2  X2010     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 79        2  X2010     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 80        2  X2010     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 81        2  X2010     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 82        2  X2010     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 83        2  X2010     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 84        2  X2010     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 85        2  X2010     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 86        2  X2010     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 87        2  X2010     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 88        2  X2010     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 89        4  X2007      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  1650
# 90        4  X2007      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   777
# 91        4  X2007      3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   123
# 92        4  X2007      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 93        4  X2007      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 94        4  X2007      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 95        4  X2007      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 96        4  X2007      8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 97        4  X2007      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 98        4  X2007     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 99        4  X2007     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 100       4  X2007     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 101       4  X2007     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 102       4  X2007     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 103       4  X2007     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 104       4  X2007     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 105       4  X2007     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 106       4  X2007     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 107       4  X2007     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 108       4  X2007     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 109       4  X2007     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 110       4  X2007     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 111       4  X2008      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  4667
# 112       4  X2008      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   666
# 113       4  X2008      3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   139
# 114       4  X2008      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 115       4  X2008      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 116       4  X2008      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 117       4  X2008      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 118       4  X2008      8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 119       4  X2008      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 120       4  X2008     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 121       4  X2008     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 122       4  X2008     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 123       4  X2008     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 124       4  X2008     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 125       4  X2008     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 126       4  X2008     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 127       4  X2008     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 128       4  X2008     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 129       4  X2008     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 130       4  X2008     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 131       4  X2008     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 132       4  X2008     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 133       4  X2009      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  4499
# 134       4  X2009      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   647
# 135       4  X2009      3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   192
# 136       4  X2009      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 137       4  X2009      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 138       4  X2009      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 139       4  X2009      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 140       4  X2009      8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 141       4  X2009      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 142       4  X2009     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 143       4  X2009     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 144       4  X2009     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 145       4  X2009     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 146       4  X2009     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 147       4  X2009     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 148       4  X2009     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 149       4  X2009     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 150       4  X2009     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 151       4  X2009     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 152       4  X2009     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 153       4  X2009     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 154       4  X2009     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 155       4  X2010      1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  5991
# 156       4  X2010      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  1069
# 157       4  X2010      3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   281
# 158       4  X2010      4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 159       4  X2010      5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 160       4  X2010      6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 161       4  X2010      7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 162       4  X2010      8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 163       4  X2010      9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 164       4  X2010     10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 165       4  X2010     11    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 166       4  X2010     12    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 167       4  X2010     13    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 168       4  X2010     14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 169       4  X2010     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 170       4  X2010     16    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 171       4  X2010     17    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 172       4  X2010     18    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 173       4  X2010     19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 174       4  X2010     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 175       4  X2010     21    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 176       4  X2010     22    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

So, you can see that if you pick `Country = 2` and `X = X2007` you have a subset which is the same as your first list (previously), etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test it on the big data. If it works, you safe me!! In any case you have given me the light!

Comment: This is even better as I need to use the I as country

Comment: This is even better as I need to use the Country as match reference to get some other data as the country name. I should append to each country list the country as id (list of 1 element). Thank you so much! I just don't replace the NA with 0 as I need the 0 as values where they are. Is there a special reason for putting the 0 that I am not aware of? I also remove the column rowRef .

Comment: No special reason. You can do what you did to have zeros and NAs.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without any external libraries.

```
L <- list()  
countries <- unique(DataMix$country)

for (c in countries) {
    ## Data for this country
    df <- DataMix[country == c, ]
    ## Order the data by RowRef and ColRef, ascending
    df <- df[order(df$RowRef, df$ColRef),]

    ## For each year...
    for (y in 4:7) {
        ## ...create a data frame to hold the data for this year and this country.
        res <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 22, ncol = 9))
        names(res) <- paste("c", 1:9, sep="")

        for (r in unique(df$RowRef)) {
            ## extract the data for this RowRef
            rowData <- df[df$RowRef == r, c(1, y)]    
            ## Copy the data under the right column
            for (col in rowData$ColRef) {                
                res[r, paste("c", col, sep="")] <- rowData[rowData$ColRef == col, 2]
            }
        }
        ## Add to the list
        L[[paste("country", c, colnames(df)[y], sep=".")]] <- res
    }
}
```

Observe that you don't need a separate column for RowRef in the new frames, just use `rownames()` to get the row reference as a string. Still, if you need it as a column you can easily add it in the main loop.

Comment: I really like the clean and easy script, Thanks! but unfortunately when I tried it , it did not put the  values at the right cells., . For ex. country 2 in 2010;  col. 2 row 1,2,3 should be 4441, 719, 224; and it is not, and there are some other incongruity. Strangely for the country 4 it is all Ok. Do you have an idea what happened?

Comment: @AnnePauline Sorry for that - I edited the script. Is this what you need?